# Call a method of mysqli-object in a class method with defined namespace

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I have two classes ('database' and 'app'). 'app' extends 'database';
both classes have the namespace 'cms'.

The problem is i want to call the method close() of a mysqli object that is stored inside an attribute of class 'database'. When i try to call that method, I get the error :

> Call to undefined method cms\database::close()

I know that in order to call a function that belongs to PHP's base namespace when currently using a diffrent namespace you can add a "\" in front of that function. But how could you do something similar with the method of a mysqli_object (like `$this->connection->close()`)? Is my whole approach wrong (if yes what should i do instead)?

I tried something like this in the destructor

```
call_user_method("close", $this->connection);
```

but i get an error which says that "close" can't be called.

My code looks as follows:

index.php

```
<?php
    use cms\app;

    require_once "class.database.php";
    require_once "class.app.php";

    $app = new app();
?>
```

class.app.php

```
<?php
namespace cms;

use cms\database;

class app extends database {
    public $connection;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->connection = new database();
    }
}

?>
```

class.database.php

```
<?php
namespace cms;

class database {
    public $connectionData = array (
        "server" => "localhost",
        "user" => "root",
        "password" => ""
    );
    public $connection;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect(
            $this->connectionData["server"],
            $this->connectionData["user"],
            $this->connectionData["password"]
        );
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        call_user_method("close", $this->connection);
    }
}

?>
```

Sorry for the long post and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If `app extends database`, why are you instantiating a `new database` in its constructor?

Comment: The Idea was to design the database class in a way that allows me to use it independantly.

Comment: But i see now that this creates more problems than it solves so I will rework my classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not namespaces. In `cms\database`, you define `$this->connection` as a `mysqli` object. The destructor accordingly wants to call `$this->connection->close()` on it. Straight forward and simple.

`cms\app` now overrides this and defines `$this->connection` as a `cms\database` object. The inherited destructor still wants to call `$this->connection->close()` on it. Well, `cms\database` doesn't have a method `close`, just as the error says.

Your issues are:

1. You're overriding `__construct` which is defining `$this->connection` as something it shouldn't be. Simply do not override `__construct` and/or at the very least call `parent::__construct` and don't redefine `$this->connection` to a different object.
2. Your `cms\app` is extending `cms\database`. This doesn't make a whole lot of sense on the face of it. *Is* your `app` *a* `database`? Could you replace any instance of `database` with an instance of `app`? Does that logically make sense? Probably not. It does not look like `app` should `extend database` at all. If you get rid of that weird relationship, your problem will be solved as well. Then look into [*Dependency Injection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: Thanks for showing me the logical issue. App should in fact not extend database. Originally my idea was to design the databse class in a way so that I could use it idependantly but this makes too many problems. The best way I think is to use 2 seperate instaces of app and database.